# mysql_real_escape_string function not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to convert my code from MySQL to MySQLi. I am trying to protect from sql injection. I have learned not to use pre_replace. I have been trying the different options as specified in my code below. The only other option that seems to work is the line of code that has mysql_escape_string below. I have tried mysql_real_escape_string and $db->real_escape_string as specified below. However, this causes the website to stop functioning all together. I am not receiving an error message though. I was wondering why the first line of code  for $FName works and the following two lines of code won't work. I have spent about 2 hours trying everything I could think of. Sorry if this question is basic but I can't find the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php require "connect.php"; ?>
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['Register'])) {
    session_start();
    $FName = mysql_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
    $LName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['LastName']);
    $Email = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
    $UName = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST ["UserName"]);          

$PW = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST ["Password"]); 
$sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO BD (FirstName, LastName, Email, UserName, Password) Values('{$FName}', '{$LName}', '{$Email}', '{$UName}','{$PW}')");

   header('Location: login.php');
}
```

?>

Comment: More info on your connection is needed. Is `$db` actually a MySQLi connection object? What is present in `connect.php`?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` would only be working if you have an active connection to the database. Finally, if your code does nothing, it suggests you do not have `display_errors` enabled. Always when developing and testing code, at the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and disable `display_errors` again in your live code.

Comment: Bare `mysql_escape_string()` works when no connection to the database has been made, which explains that one working. So really, this is down to verifying that whatever connection you attempted to make in `connection.php` is a valid MySQLi object.

Comment: side note - what are you doing to the submitted password ?

Comment: @NinoŠkopac The OP is trying to understand the difference between 3 methods, and is seeking help with getting the _right one_ to work. This isn't a case of haphazardly mixing APIs and hoping for the best.

Comment: my connect file works. It is as follows:      
Also my connect file works. It is as follows:
<?php
$con =new mysqli ("local host", "name", "PW", "users") or die ("Could not connect to our database!");
?>

Comment: @ScottSchoener `new mysqli` will **never** return a *falsy* value so the `or die` is useless (it's always useless as an error control mechanism but in this case, it's extra useless). Place this just before your `$con = new mysqli...` line ~ `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: *" I was wondering why the first line of code for $FName works "* - *"I have tried mysql_real_escape_string and $db->real_escape_string as specified below."* - First part of that, hard to believe. Second part, you're using the wrong variable; there.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski okay dude, you got it.

Comment: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) on line 13

Comment: Line 13 is 
$LName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['LastName']);

Comment: OK. First I am sorry. I am a newbie and spending a lot of time trying to learn the basics. I am trying to get away from bad practice and realize I have a long way to go. The password line in my code will be changed once I have the basics down. Even though my DB is connected it appears that mysl_real_escape isn't recognizing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated in comments that this is your connection:

```
$con =new mysqli ("local host", "name", "PW", "users")
```

yet you're using `$db` as the variable for `$Email`. That should be `$con`.

Plus, `local host` should be in one word, `localhost`.

```
$con =new mysqli ("localhost", "name", "PW", "users")
```

while checking for errors for it:

```
$con =new mysqli ("localhost", "name", "PW", "users");

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $con->connect_errno . ') '
            . $con->connect_error);
}
```

- Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Then these will never work:

```
$FName = mysql_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
$LName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['LastName']);
```

as you are mixing MySQL APIs. Those different APIs/functions do not intermix with each other. You need to use the same from connection to query.

Including:

```
$Email = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
```

Therefore, this whole block:

```
$FName = mysql_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
$LName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['LastName']);
$Email = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
```

needs to be changed to:

```
$FName = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
$LName = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['LastName']);
$Email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: My friend. I can't thank you enough. Even though I wasn't perfectly clear in my description of the problem you have figured out the solution. By adding $con-> it did the trick. My problem is that I read so many tutorials that seem to assume I know what every thing is. I just needed to see an example and yours was perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @ScottSchoener You're welcome Scott. Glad I was of help, *cheers*